# Should I use ConfigureAwait(false) on my Task.Delay inside my Task.Run action?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task

In my WPF MVVM app I have some background task that runs forever, I create it like so:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (IsStarted)
        {
            // Do some processing and update the UI via bound properties.
        }

        await Task.Delay(300);
    }
});
```

Should I change it to `await Task.Delay(300).ConfigureAwait(false);`? I can't tell from looking around but it sounds like it might be redundant because it's being awaited from a thread pool thread already.

Comment: Because in your case it is doesn't matter where execution continous - you should use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` - it will be more efficient in your case when you execute delay in the loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I change it to await Task.Delay(300).ConfigureAwait(false);? I can't tell from looking around but it sounds like it might be redundant because it's being awaited from a thread pool thread already.

It would be redundant since the method has no context to capture in the first place.

However, as a stylistic preference, I would still use it. The presence of `ConfigureAwait(false)` informs the reader of the code that the remainder of this method does not need to resume in its original context.

Answer (score 1):

Call your async task with do not await.

```
dispatcherTimer_Tick().DoNotAwait();
```

Your Async task will run every 10 seconds without distrubing UI. You can modify it as you wish. By doing this kinda method your UI never get struck or hang and it will run forever.

```
private async Task dispatcherTimer_Tick()
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
    EventHandler tickHandler = (s, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(true);

    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    timer.Tick += tickHandler;
    timer.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
       // Run your background service and UI update here
        await tcs.Task;
    }

}
```

Comment: So do you see a benefit of this approach over the one I'm using? It seems like the timing might be more precise using your approach. Rather than 'wait a second, do the work, wait a second' like mine, yours is 'every second, do the work'.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by `DispatcherTimer` class.

First of all you need to initialise the class as follow.

```
DispatcherTimer myBackGroundProcess=new DispatcherTimer();
```

Now you required to register event to your `DispatcherTimer` object like this.

```
myBackGroundProcess.Tick += new EventHandler(myBackGroundProcess_Tick);
myBackGroundProcess.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
myBackGroundProcess.Start();
```

In `TimeSpan` you can mention your time to call your method it takes argument in(hour,minute,second).

At last you need to write a method that you have register with `DispatcherTimer`object.

```
public void myBackGroundProcess_Tick()
{
     //Do Something
}
```

Hence in my code my method `myBackGroundProcess_Tick()` will call at every time after every 2 minutes forever.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense but it seems like it's doing something different. As far as I know this uses the UI thread for the `//Do something`, but my code is keeping that processing on a thread pool thread.